# Complex RegEx Find Replace in Sublime Text

Tags: regex, sublimetext3

I have a massive JSON file and inside it, there is a lot of this:

```
"Description":"<br><br><br> <table border=\"1\" padding=\"0\"> <tr><td>CCGcode</td><td>00G</td></tr> <tr><td>CCGname</td><td>NHS Newcastle North and East CCG</td></tr>"
"Description":"<br><br><br> <table border=\"1\" padding=\"0\"> <tr><td>CCGcode</td><td>00J</td></tr> <tr><td>CCGname</td><td>NHS North Durham CCG</td></tr>"
```

The above is surrounded with a lot of other stuff, similiar to [this](http://pastebin.com/LJ29cVg4). I would like to replace any such occurrences with:

```
"Description":"NHS Newcastle North and East CCG"
"Description":"NHS North Durham CCG"
```

But I do not know how to. I've tried multiple Regular Expressions, but couldn't get it to work.

Comment: Arghh! Using sublimetext (or any other text editor) to do that is a waste of time. Using the programming language you want that can deal with JSON and making the replacement you want will be from far more handy.

Comment: In what sense is it a waste of time? why do you think so?

Comment: Because when you can deal with JSON in programming language, you have easily an access to the target value, once you get it, make the changes you want, and save the JSON. But if you use a regex way, the replacement (if you find it) can correctly change the field you want, but it may also change fields you don't want.

Comment: I see, but the JSON data I'm working on is from somewhere else. It has not come from a database in my application. It is simply a JSON file I got from somewhere.

Comment: It's not a problem, it's possible to load a local file with a programming language and to save it after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use capturing groups to capture the text you want for later use.

Regex:

```
^("Description":").*<td>([^<>\n]*).*$
```

OR

```
^("Description":").*?<td>CCGname<\/td><td>([^<>\n]*).*$
```

Replacement string:

```
$1$2"
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/aZ6pN5/6)

Comment: Sorry, I meant the name of the CCG should be after description. Updated my Question.

Comment: Hmm, is something wrong with Sublime Text 3? The RegEx you've given me does not seem to work there! [screenshot](http://screencast.com/t/mVh7zUPui9Mv)

Comment: use \ instead of `$` in the replacement like `\1\2"`

Comment: Still not finding any matches in ST3. I believe the replace comes later. It is the matching that isn't working. It first has to match stuff, then replace stuff (I think).

Comment: updated my question. I think I didn't explain clearly enough that the above code is surrounded by other stuff.

Comment: Added that new source to your RegEx tester shows that it does indeed fail when considering the surrounding content.

Answer (score 0):

If your tool supports look behinds:

```
(?<="Description":").*?CCGname</td><td>(.*?)<.*
```

Replace with `$1`